# What conditions do I need for this calculation to work? (Product rule differentiation of bilinear form)

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Let $b(\cdot,\cdot):X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear mapping where $X$ is a Banach space.

Consider functions $f:[0,T]\to X$ and $g:[0,T] \to X$. What assumptions do I need on $b$ so that this is valid:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b(f(t+h),g(t+h))-b(f(t),g(t))}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b(f(t+h),g(t+h))\pm b(f(t+h), g(t)) -b(f(t),g(t))}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b(f(t+h),g(t+h)-g(t))+b(f(t+h)-f(t),g(t))}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b(f(t+h),g(t+h)-g(t))}{h}+\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b(f(t+h)-f(t),g(t))}{h}=b(\lim_{h \to 0}f(t+h),\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h})+b(\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h},g(t))$$
$$=b(f(t), g'(t)) + b(f'(t), g(t))$$

Obviously $f$ and $g$ need to be differentiable in time. So say $f, g \in C^1([0,T];X)$. But not sure how to formulate the condition on $b$. It should be something like "$b$ is continuous"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that the bilinear form is a bounded operator (i.e. continuous). If it is such, you can freely pass limits through.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what is the topology that $b$ should be continuous with respect to. He wants $b$ to be a bilinear map on functions, rather than on scalar values.

Comment: Sorry, I made it a bit confusing. I agree with your answer if $b$ takes real numbers. Are you aware of what is needed if $b:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$? So in my calculation above, $f:[0,T] \to X$ say. Would boudedness of $b$ suffice? Here $X$ is some Banach space.

Comment: You make a good point. I'll think about this and edit my post when I figure it out.

Comment: @matt.w First of all, you need to define what norm you are considering before we can even continue. There are a wealth of norms you can place on functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I edited my question. Let me think but I am not sure we need any norm other than the norm on $X$..

Comment: Yeah I see that now. You're right, we are interested in the norm on $X$.

Comment: I agree with this answer now that the question has been changed so that $b$ is a bilinear map on the pointwise values of the functions rather than on the functions themselves.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Really. Hmm I did not think boundedness is good enough.

Comment: @matt.w Continuity and boundedness are effectively the same property for linear operators on Banach spaces.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you. I was aware of that but was unsure that bringing in the limit on the outside to inside both arguments of the bilinear form was using just continuity. Need to go back to basics...